# Javascript performance test in continuous integration process

Tags: javascript, performance, continuous-integration, benchmarking

How to test javascript in continuous integration process ? What tools do you use ?

I try to follow the evolution of the execution time of a script file changes.

Answer (score 0):

We use [jasmine](http://pivotal.github.io/jasmine/) to write our test cases and execute them with [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/).

Comment: It return performance metrics (execution time) ? and report with previous test ?

Comment: No, but please read on. Our codebase is structured using Ruby on Rails. As such, we have added [guard-jasmine](https://github.com/netzpirat/guard-jasmine) as a dependency which executes these test cases when we run rake spec. This in turn is run by our CruiseControl.rb instance which reports new failures. We have a perf test suite too but it's not run as part of our continuous deployment (we deploy to production several times a day) process. After every 2 sprints, we spend a week on perf tuning. Till now, this has worked for us.

Comment: If you are planning to write something for this, it'll be awesome and I'll be glad to help. Just reply to me as a comment.